# linking binary trees in C

Tags: c

I made a program where I have a main function, a file which contains another function, and a header file. 
My main looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "header.h"

int main()
{...
show_in_postorder(root,0);
}
```

In the file I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"
void show_in_postorder (Tree *root, int level)
{...}
```

And the header is this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct Nodetype
{
    char nod;
    struct Nodetype *left,*right;
}Tree;
Tree *root;
void show_in_postorder (Tree *root, int level);
#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

The error that I get is: undefined reference to "show_in_postorder", at the line where I call the postorder function in main.

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: what compiler do you use? how do you use it?

Comment: I made a similar problem with the same compiler and it worked, so it`s not the compiler`s fault.

Comment: @user3078259: nobody says it's the compiler's fault, just answer the questions that have been asked by the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: CodeBlocks. PS: solved it. The problem was that I didn`t checked the "Release" and "Debug" properties when I created the C source file.

Comment: @user3078259 Please answer and accept your own answer so other people facing the same problem can use this question to find help.